# Having trouble with detection of whether this is a BST or not

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Trying to run a recursive algorithm to find out if a certain tree is a BST(Binary search tree).

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
    boolean isBST = true;
    if(root == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(root.left != null){
        if( isLessThan(root.data, root.left.data) == false ) {
            isBST = false;
            return isBST;
        } else
            checkBST(root.left);
    }
    if(root.right != null){
        if(isGreaterThan(root.data, root.right.data) == false) {
            isBST = false;
            return isBST;
        } else
            checkBST(root.right);
    }
    return isBST;
}


boolean isLessThan(int value1, int value2){
    if(value2< value1){
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

boolean isGreaterThan(int value1, int value2){
    if(value1 < value2){
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

I'm not sure whats wrong with my algorithm. Any help?

Comment: To clarify, is the problem that you don't understand how a BST works or is the problem that you don't understand your code?

Comment: dont understand my code thought i was on the write track but im stuck

Comment: Please fix your indentations. They are *horrible*.

Comment: What is the point of `isBST = false; return isBST;`? Why not just `return false;`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your implementation ignores return values of recursive invocations of the method:

```
checkBST(root.left);
...
checkBST(root.right);
```

Regardless of the return value, your code continues on. Instead, it should check the return value, and return `false` if the check of a subtree returned `false`:

```
if (!checkBST(root.left)) {
    return false;
}
...
if (!checkBST(root.right)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: its weird i tried inserting that and its still giving me the wrong output

Comment: this is really annoying me because i feel like this is something i should be able to do

Comment: @SJackson193 You should be able to simplify this a lot by removing the `== true` and `== false` parts, and eliminating `isBST` variable altogether. Also, you should return `true` for `root` that is `null`, because `null` represents an empty BST.

Comment: @SJackson193 Where does the tree come from? Are you building it in your code, or is it passed to you?

Comment: its passed to e